# dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of r-base-core in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, r

I have attempted to install R new version from source code however it did not work. so I uninstalled and reinstalled R again using the amd64.

R is still not woking when I run :

```
$which R 
command not found
```

I am trying to clean all the files before reinstalling again.

```
$dpkg -l | grep r-base-core  
r-base-core 4.3.2-1.2004.0   amd64   GNU R core of statistical computation and graphics system.
```

So I know there are files remaining. This is what I did next to try to force remove the files.

```
apt-get install --fix-broken

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
~$ sudo apt-get update

Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu20.04/amd64  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo: unable to resolve host : No address associated with hostname
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  
11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq r-base-core

dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of r-base-core:

 r-recommended depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.2-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-withr depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-viridislite depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-vctrs depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-utf8 depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-tibble depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-systemfonts depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-svglite depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-survival depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-stanheaders depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-spatial depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-scales depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-rstan depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-rpart depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-rlang depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-rcppparallel depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-rcppeigen depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-rcpp depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-rcolorbrewer depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-r6 depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-quickjsr depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-ps depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-processx depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-pkgconfig depends on r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200416-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-pkgconfig depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-pkgbuild depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-pillar depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-4.2004.0).
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-munsell depends on r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200416-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-munsell depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.2-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-matrixstats depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-matrix depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-mass depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-mass depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-magrittr depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-loo depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-lifecycle depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-4.2004.0).
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-labeling depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-kernsmooth depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-jsonlite depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-isoband depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-inline depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-gtable depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-gridextra depends on r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200416-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-gridextra depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-glue depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-ggplot2 depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.2-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-farver depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-fansi depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-desc depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-cpp11 depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-colorspace depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-codetools depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.2-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-cli depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-class depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-class depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-checkmate depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-callr depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-boot depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-bh depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-backports depends on r-base-core.
 r-base-html depends on r-base-core.
 r-cran-pkgconfig depends on r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200416-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-pkgconfig depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-4.2004.0).
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-munsell depends on r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200416-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-munsell depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.2-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-mass depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-mass depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-4.2004.0).
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-gridextra depends on r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200416-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-gridextra depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.2-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.2-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.
 r-cran-class depends on r-base-core (>= 4.3.1-1.2004.0).
 r-cran-class depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r-base-core

~$ apt-cache depends r-base-core | grep Depends
  Depends: zip
  Depends: unzip
  Depends: libpaper-utils
  Depends: xdg-utils
 |Depends: libblas3
  Depends: <libblas.so.3>
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcairo2
  Depends: libcurl4
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgomp1
  Depends: libicu66
  Depends: libjpeg8
 |Depends: liblapack3
  Depends: <liblapack.so.3>
  Depends: liblzma5
  Depends: libpango-1.0-0
  Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0
  Depends: libpcre2-8-0
  Depends: libpng16-16
  Depends: libreadline8
  Depends: libtcl8.6
  Depends: libtiff5
  Depends: libtk8.6
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxt6
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: ucf
  Depends: ca-certificates
```

At this level, I couldn't force remove R base core files. Any thought how to solve this problem and enable safe installation if R.

Comment: Hi, if you want to try to build R from source you might find helpful this guide: https://contributor.r-project.org/rdevguide/GetStart.html#building-r. As long as you have [these dependencies](https://contributor.r-project.org/rdevguide/GetStart.html#ubuntu) you should be able to do it along your apt installation (if you select a different path to install it).

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 errors:

1. nvidia repo isn't set correctly.
2. `sudo` error: `sudo: unable to resolve host : No address associated with hostname`.
3. Dependencies problem when building `r`.

---

1. Setting up the [nvidia repository](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html#installing-with-apt):

Removing the existing repo (comment the URL):

```
sudo sed -e '/libnvidia-container/s/^/#/' -i /etc/apt/sources.list{.d/*,}
```

Setting up the repository:

```
curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg 
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/$(ARCH) /" | 
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list
```

2 Solving `sudo` error:

```
echo -e "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost" |sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

3. Solving the missing dependencies:

As said in the [`r` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html#installation), sometimes you need to enable backports to build `r` correctly:

> Installation and compilation of R or some of its packages may require Ubuntu packages from the “backports” repositories. Therefore, it is suggested to activate the backports repositories with an entry like
> `deb https://<my.favorite.ubuntu.mirror>/ focal-backports main restricted universe`

```
echo "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
sudo apt update
```